# How Can i convert String to Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two variables with data and DataConvert I want to convert data like
DataConvert

```js
let data="{'one':{'id':'2'},'one':{'id':'2'}}"
let DataConvert={'one':{'id':'2'},'one':{'id':'2'}}

console.info(data)
console.info(DataConvert)
```

Comment: You'll have to use `eval()` for this. Why don't you make the string in JSON format so you can use `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: The only difference between your string and JSON is that it should use double quotes around the strings instead of single quotes.

Comment: i also try this but not work can you convert this like DataConvert format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only built-in function that will do it is `eval()`.

```js
let data="{'one':{'id':'2'},'two':{'id':'2'}}";
let DataConvert;
eval(`DataConvert = ${data}`);

console.info(data)
console.info(DataConvert)
```

In your jsfiddle you have `\r\n` inside some of the strings, which is not valid JavaScript. If you want those to be kept literally in the result, you need to escape them before calling `eval()`:

```
data = data.replace(/\r/g, '\\r').replace(/\n/g, '\\n');
```

But this is dangerous if you don't control the source of the string, since it will execute arbitrary expression in `data`.

If you change the quotes to double quotes, you can use `JSON.parse()`, which is safer.

```js
let data='{"one":{"id":"2"},"two":{"id":"2"}}';
let DataConvert = JSON.parse(data);

console.info(data)
console.info(DataConvert)
```

Note that object keys have to be unique, you can't have two properties named `"one"`. I changed the second one to `"two"` to make it valid.

Comment: Technically, duplicate keys are not invalid in JSON…

Comment: Sir, please check the how can I resolve this issue single and double quotes very confusing

Comment: You have `\r\n` at the end of some of the URLs. This is creating invalid JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you, sir, for your guide I understood everything